# yesod persistent: get list of entities from list of keys

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

suppose I have `fooIds :: [Key Foo]`. How would I get `foos :: [Foo]`?

I tried

```
do
    foos <- map get fooIds
```

but it gives me

```
No instance for (MonadBaseControl IO m0)
  arising from a use of `get'
```

I assume because I need to use `runDB`. But I'm not quite sure how to work it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
foos <- runDB $ mapM get fooIds
```

However, that will give you a list of `Maybe Foo`s. You can turn that into a list of `Foo`s by either replacing `get` with `get404` or by using `catMaybes`. Note that these are two different approaches: with the first, if any ID does not exist, the user will get a 404. With the second, that key will simply be ignored.

Comment: Ah, thanks! what if instead I had `mfooIds :: [Maybe (Key Foo)]` and wanted to get `mfoos :: [Maybe Foo]` ? How would I make a `get` function that takes a `Maybe Key` ?

Comment: Nevermind, got it with  `mfoos <- runDB $ mapM (maybe (return Nothing) get) mfooIds`

Comment: If the database is remote, is there any difference (amount of requests-wise) between `runDB $ mapM get fooIds` and `fmap (runDB . get) fooIds`?

Comment: Each runDB call will introduce another database transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful approach would be

```
foos <- runDB $ mapM getJustEntity fooIds
```