# Select with list of keys Persistent (Yesod)

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I need to fetch a list of entities from a list of keys, with Persistent (Yesod)

Say I have a `Model` and its corresponding `ModelId`. I have with me:

```
keys :: [ModelId]
```

and I need to get

```
models :: [Model]
```

The current best way of doing that seems to be:

```
models' <- mapM get keys
models <- return $ Data.Maybe.catMaybes models'
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Does persistent queue up the fetch requests or execute them one by one?

There's the same question at [yesod persistent: get list of entities from list of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793837/yesod-persistent-get-list-of-entities-from-list-of-keys) but I would like to know whether this is the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: I don't know how yesod performs requests, but you could simplify this command to `models <- fmap catMaybes $ mapM get keys` so you don't have the intermediate `models'` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question well, you can achieve it by trying something like this:

```
models' <- selectList [ModelId <-. keys] []
```

By using `mapM` you will query the database `length keys` times, while `selectList` performs a single query.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Didn't know I could use ModelId to select Models.